# Method not found: 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0> NHibernate.Linq.LinqExtensionMethods.Query(NHibernate.IStatelessSession)'

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, iqueryable

I have a problem when upgrading NHibernate from 4.1.2 to 5.2.3 and Target Framework from 4.5 to 4.6.2 (to compatible with NH 5.x). The problem occurs when I execute the query using LINQ (it worked well before):

```
service.Query.Where(p => p.Approved).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is detail message exception:

> Method not found: 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1 NHibernate.Linq.LinqExtensionMethods.Query(NHibernate.IStatelessSession)'.

I notice when I call service.Query, the system will throw an exception:

> 'service.Query' threw an exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException'

What did I miss?

Comment: Is this: `)).` a typo?

Comment: That's my mistake when edit, not cause of the above error. thanks for remind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app is still trying to call old extension `Query` method which was removed in NHibernate 5. `Query` is `IStatelessSession/ISession` interface method since NHibernate 5.

Exception you see means that your app is not properly recompiled with new NHibernate dlls. Make sure that all your projects reference new dlls (or nuget package) and you have no compilation errors (possible case - you run last successful build before upgrade but with newer dlls).

Comment: Thank you. Finally, I found the problem. This caused by my project execute a query by an intermediate library, it means when I call service.query, it isn't use NH query directly, it call the function Query of intermediate library and the intermediate library call to LinqExtensionMethods.Query, but in NH 5.2.3, this method doesn't exist in LinqExtensionMethods class.

Comment: @ThanhLD I need your help to resolve the issue. I am having the same problem. How did you resolve the problem?

Comment: @CodeRunner I settle my problem by change old DLL by new dll which appropriate with current NHibernate version.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it still works for me with 4.1.2, so I downgraded it to version 4.1.2.4000. It works fine for now.